# $f(x^2*f(y)^2) = f(x^2) * f(y)$

Tags: functional-equations

$$f(x^2 * f(y)^2) = f(x^2) * f(y)$$
$$f:{\mathbb Q}^+ \rightarrow {\mathbb Q}^+$$
$x,y \in {\mathbb Q}^+$

I have been given the following equation and information and am supposed to find all functions which satisfy this equation. 
I have found $f(x)=1$ and $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ work.
How can I prove more exist/ do not exist?

Comment: Thank you for helping me with the edit.

Comment: I would suggest sticking with my formatting. $*$ for multiplication is nonstandard, and usually you only use the phrase "following equation" when the equation comes after that part of the text.

Comment: What is the standard symbol for multiplication then?

Comment: Multiplication is most often indicated by simple juxtaposition, or "$\cdot$", or "$\times$".

Comment: Since the square root of a rational number isn't always rational, and $f\colon \mathbb Q^+\rightarrow\mathbb Q^+$, $f\colon x\mapsto\sqrt x$ can't be a solution.

Comment: Do you include $0$ in $\Bbb{Q}^+$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe, we do the following manipulation: let $x = 1$ :
$$f(f(y)^2) = f(x^2 \cdot f(y)^2) = f(x^2) \cdot f(y) = f(1) \cdot f(y) = f(y \cdot f(1)^2) $$

*Case:* Assume the function is left-invertible (or simply invertible), which tends to be a desirable quality for solutions of functional equations, you get:

$$f(y)^2 = y \cdot f(1)^2$$

Which, since $f(y) \geq 0$, becomes:

$$f(y) = f(1) \sqrt{y}$$

However, in order for $f(y) \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}$, the only valid choice is $f(1) = 0$. That is, 
$$f(y) = 0$$

**Note:** The zero function isn't invertible, but I added it effectively falls into the next case, as well as your discovery that $f(x) = 1$ is a solution as well.

*Case:* $f$ possesses no left inverse. So $f$ is not injective.

This is where everything starts to break apart. You can start going down the Rabbits hole of tossing away assumptions.

Observe, let $x = 1$ and $y = 0$, then:

$$f(1) \cdot f(0) = f(f(0)^2) = f(0 \cdot f(1)^2) = f(0) $$

And letting $x = 0 = y$:

$$f(0) = f(0) \cdot f(0) \in \{ 0, 1 \}$$

*Case:* $f(0) = 1 = f(1)$. Then the equation becomes:

$$f(f(y)^2) = f(y)$$

This is simply a recurrence relation over $\mathbb{Q}^{+}$. Given a value $y$, choose the value $f(y) = m \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}$. Then:

$$f(m^2) = m$$

So this takes care of all the values $\{ x \in \mathbb{Q}^{+} : \exists y \in \mathbb{Q}^{+} \text{ such that } y^2 = x\}$. For the remainder of the values, we can make a variety of choices. Specifically, we can let those values go to one. That is, we can have the function:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\sqrt{x} & \sqrt{x} \in \mathbb{Q}^{+} \\
1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

But we can also try many other potential functions. You might not be able to construct a function that is continuous however. This because if you have a sequence of numbers from the right that approach $y$ that are rationally square rootable, and a sequence from the left that are rationally square rootable, you can try to choose $f(y)$ to such that

$$x_n \rightarrow y \leftarrow z_n$$
$$\sqrt{x_n} \rightarrow f(y) \leftarrow \sqrt{z_n}$$

But due to the incompleteness of $\mathbb{Q}$, I don't remember if there is a way of choosing a satisfactory alternative $f(y)$.

*Case:* $f(0) = 0$. I'll let you take this from here. It's very similar to the function we found in the previous case, except $f(0) = 0$ is stated explicitly.

Edit: Totally assumed $0 \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}$. If not, replace with an $\epsilon \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}$.

Comment: Nice start! Note that $f(y)=0$ is not a valid solution, since also $0\notin\Bbb{Q}^+$.

Comment: Note also that $x,y\in \mathbb{Q}^+$, so we cannot let $x=0$ or $y=0$.